# checking if string is numeric is not working in vb

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to check if a string is numeric but in vain. here is my code:

```
If Val(fnumField.Text.Trim) > 0 Or fnumField.Text.Trim = "0" Or Val(phnField.Text.Trim) > 0 Or phnField.Text.Trim = "0" Or Val(ophnField.Text.Trim) > 0 Or _
        ophnField.Text.Trim = "0" Or Val(treeField.Text.Trim) > 0 Or treeField.Text.Trim = "0" Then 
    messageBox.Show("number")
Else
    messageBox.Show("not number")
EndIf
```

The problem I have is that when I run the program and insert a character string like "abcd" in one of the textfields like "fnumField", it still executes the code in the "if" and not in the "else". What am I not doing right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
If (Val(fnumField.Text.Trim) > 0 Or fnumField.Text.Trim = "0") And (Val(phnField.Text.Trim) > 0 Or phnField.Text.Trim = "0") And (Val(ophnField.Text.Trim) > 0 Or
        ophnField.Text.Trim = "0") And (Val(treeField.Text.Trim) > 0 Or treeField.Text.Trim = "0") Then 
    messageBox.Show("number")
Else
    messageBox.Show("not number")
EndIf
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working now. So I only had to look at my logic :)